# Guidance for security architecture of jquery mobile/facebook/paypal/asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, facebook, security, jquery-mobile, paypal

I have a jquery mobile app that uses ajax to make calls to my asp.net web methods written in C#. These methods query a SQL Server database and return data. At this point no user registration is necessary. I also have some facebook integration using the javascript sdk, in terms of likes, comments, and posting to a user's wall/timeline.

The next step in my development is that the user will be able to pay a fee to essentially get data entered into my database. I would like to avoid getting into user/password management, and instead rely on a facebook login (and later maybe other social networks, for now let's stick with facebook).

So the workflow that I see is:

1. I prompt the user to login to facebook if not logged in already
2. user clicks 'buy' on my website, which is a paypal button
3. user gets sent to a secure paypal page, makes the payment, and is returned to my site
4. with a successful payment, I call a web method to insert the new data, which is marked as being entered by this facebook user. The web method will connect with the same sql server account that does all the fetching, there will not be sql server user accounts for individual visitors.

I see some interesting security holes here. Like someone writing code to directly call my insert web method, without having made any payments. I'm looking for guidance on how to tie all these steps together in a secure way so that in the end, I am guaranteed that any data that is entered was 
a) paid for
and b) entered by the currently logged in facebook user

I have read the facebook login developer docs, the paypal developer docs, and the microsoft asp.net application services docs. I can mostly understand each one, but I am getting lost tying them all together in a single, secure transaction. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is - in your insert web method, verify that a payment has been made by the user. You can do that in couple of ways. Use the PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification) to confirm the payment or switch over to the PayPal Express Checkout API so you can verify the payment programmatically after the user is redirected back to your site. Here is a quick how-to guide that would help you implement this: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/how-to/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've been reading more on the x.com site, and it gets even more confusing. There are merchant APIs, SDKs, etc - not sure where to begin. Not sure if I will need an SSL certificate to have an https page, I was hoping that would all be handled by the paypal site. But in the link you provided, the is a password being sent. Unfortunately it is not clear to me where this is being sent from: a secure client page or a back end server using one of the server SDKs? For a paypal and a security newbie, it is really hard to get an overview of the big picture. More reading to do!

Comment: What about Payment Data Transfer? That seems like it could work as well.

Comment: The username, password and signature are the PayPal's API Credentials (not end consumer's credentials). You would need to pass them in all API calls you make to PayPal so it can authenticate and authorize your calls as needed. Since these are secure API Credentials, you would need to make these calls from a server side (not client side). For Express checkout API, you can use the merchant SDK that includes support for those APIs. The SDK takes care of a lot of implementation details for you. You don't need an SSL cert for this.

Comment: Payment Data Transfer is an advanced process to dynamically update your payment information on the PayPal's review your payment page that's rendered for the end consumer. Typically use of this is when you need to recalculate the shipping and tax based on the consumer's address and display it to the consumer on the PayPal hosted pages.

Comment: According to this link, you need an internet merchant account to use express checkout: www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_additional-payment-overview. It implies that I should already be able to accept credit cards directly, and am just adding paypal as a new payment method. I don't have a merchant acoount, I just want to use regular ol' business paypal. And I don't have https. It sounds like there really isn't a solution for regular paypal business account. I must say that trying to navigate the paypal documentation has been one of the most frustrating experiences in recent memory.

Comment: yeah sorry about the confusing documentation - a lot of things in works to improve this. Regarding merchant account need - no you don't need one. You can use PayPal Business Account for Express Checkout - more details here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/express-checkout